# How to make table updating more efficient in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

in the following code I am trying to go through a list of customer IDs and update the *Confirmed* field to match sysdate in the given records. The problem is, if I do this for around 40k customers separately, it will take between 15-20 minutes to run, witch would be a bit too much for such an operation. Could you please give me suggestions on how I can improve my code to run faster and/or reduce the number of database requests?

```
foreach (int i in confirmCustomers)
{
    queryString = @"
        UPDATE TABLENAME
        SET CONFIRMED = @datenow
        WHERE ID = @id";

    command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection, transaction);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datenow", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Using a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) is one option - _"Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters."_

Comment: Is `CONFIRMED` in fact a string in the database?

Comment: @GSerg it is a DATETIME field indicating the time that the given customer has been last confirmed as active.

Comment: Then why are you converting your datetime to a string when passing it to the command? Another problem is that you are creating a new `SqlCommand` for each item; if you'd rather keep the loop and not go with the table-value parameters, you should create one `SqlCommand` and reuse it in the loop.

Comment: Your data access strategy is pretty outdated.  Consider using the Execute functionality that's available in Dapper or Entity Framework instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks. I've been told the very same thing by a colleague. I'll look into it.

Comment: For Entity Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016+ you can append all the IDs in a JSON array like

```
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"
```

and pass that as a string parameter to the command, and run:

```
queryString = @"
    UPDATE TABLENAME
    SET CONFIRMED = @datenow
    WHERE ID in (select cast(value as int) from openjson( @ids ) )";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Would that not make the query string too long? How many characters long can a query string be in SqlCommand? (Sorry I'v e only been coding in c# for a month...)

Comment: You can also use a simple `where ID in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, why are you making it complicated?

Comment: @Blindy Because there is a [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) on how many items the `in()` clause can contain.

Comment: There's no limit on how long a parameter can be.  You're not appending the values into the query, you're sending JSON data as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidB Would probably be better with `select value from openjson(@ids) with (value int '$')`.

Comment: @GSerg  Yes.  For 100,000 values your query costs about 30ms of CPU time vs 47ms for mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        string queryString = @"UPDATE TABLENAME SET CONFIRMED = @datenow WHERE ID = @id";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection, transaction);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datenow", SqlDbType.DateTime));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int));
        command.Prepare();
        foreach (int i in confirmCustomers)
        {
            command.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
            command.Parameters["@datenow"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that would do any good performance-wise:(

Comment: @TamásKovács It should have a noticeable impact because it does reuse the command. It is missing the [`.Prepare()` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Prepare) though.

Comment: OK @GSerg, I'll look into it.

Comment: [Don't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already)

Comment: @BillTür, ok. What should I use instead?

Comment: @TamásKovács, I had changed my answer, take a look

Comment: Much better now. All that's left is removing the `.ToString()`.

Comment: thank you @GSerg, i didn't understand the using of preapre() at the first time i read the documantary of MS, so I think thats now seems correct

according to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabular approach by using string_split function as following..

```
/* init query string */
string queryString = @"
    UPDATE tbl
        SET tbl.CONFIRMED = getdate()
    FROM TABLENAME tbl
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID FROM string_split(@ids, ',')
    ) ids
    WHERE tbl.ID = ids.ID";

/* init command */
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection, transaction);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ids", SqlDbType.Text, 4000));
command.Prepare();

/* init list of id */
List<int> ids = new List<int>();

/* update table for each confirm customers */
foreach (int i in confirmCustomers)
{
    /* add id to list */
    ids.add(i);

    /* update 100 customer ids */
    if (ids.Count == 100)
    {
        command.Parameters[0].Value = String.Join(",", ids);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        /* reset list of id */
        ids.Clear();
    }
}

/* update remains customer id */
if (ids.Count > 0)
{
    command.Parameters[0].Value = String.Join(",", ids);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Hope this helps.